# Radio button bind with textbox to localstorage or cookie not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

This script is adapted from one of the user here, however once I added in the checkbox bind with textbox, it doesnt work properly.

E.g from http://jsfiddle.net/TzPW9/315/ once I click on 'others' option in question 2 it is stuck no matter how I change my answer, once I refresh it will automatically return to 'others' option. Most likely the issue is with this line onwards

P.S my javascript is really quite bad.

Thank you I will appreciate any help!

```
    $('div.radio_button input:radio').bind('change', function() {
        $('#' + this.id + 'box').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
        // save the data on change
        storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'not');
    }).each(function() {
        // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
        var val = storedData.get(this.id);
        if (val == 'checked')
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        if (val == 'not')
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        if (val)
            $(this).trigger('change');
    });
```

Comment: -1, isolate the issue

Comment: I am not sure what you really meant, however I have removed the excess code that are working well and left the part which is problematic

Comment: I'm not going to review the question, but I have removed the dv. Though I still do believe you can isolate the issue. Isolation takes form when you have a few lines of code that replicate the issue without being the issue. We don't want to see all your code, but we do want to see a few lines of code that are *independent* in themselves that still have the ability to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

One reason is this line:

```
$(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

use this instead:

```
$(this).prop('checked', true);
```

The other reason is that when you for example set the second option in your radio buttons you don't delete (or clear) the previous status in the storage.

What happens then is f.ex (action pseudo) -

Setting option 1 (your 31a):

```
set(31a, checked)
```

Then you load and it works because.

```
get(31a = checked)
get(32b = null)
```

Now set option two:

```
set(31b, checked);
```

Now load and this happen:

```
get(31a = checked)
get(32b = checked)
```

A radio button needs to have only one option set, so it is forced to pick one and will chose the last one. That's why the last option is always set.

### Solution

when you change option you need to delete (or clear) the previous option.

The simplest way is to clear the storage and save all options over again. This is not noticeable for the user though (unless you have thousands of items to save).

The second method will require you to keep track of the grouping of the radio button group and set all the values accordingly when an option in that group changes. You can use separate prefixes if you use different forms and use `Object.keys(localStorage)` to iterate through the keys to compare prefixes (or similar function for cookies).

Working version with a brute-force approach on updating storage:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/TzPW9/317/

```
function updateAll() {
    localStorage.clear(); //brute-force here..
    $('div.radio_button input').each(function () {
        storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'not');
    });
}
```

The code that triggers it:

```
$('div.radio_button input:radio').bind('change', function () {
    $('#' + this.id + 'box').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    // save the data on change
    updateAll();
    //storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'not');
});
```

Of course you will need to do the same for cookies so the best choice is probably to incorporate a 'clear' method on your storage object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand why this code cannot be used this way. I will try to find a solution using the 2nd method you proposed. Another way I will also try to store by name instead of ID so that e.g. 31 => 31a if option A is set. I wouldnt be able to use a brute force method as this is just one page of the many page survey I will be creating. Thanks again!

Comment: @lwj5 the brute-force was just for example as the error is else-where. You can collect the keys Object.keys(localStorage) and iterate through them and use removeItem to delete only the keys related to this form (tip: use a specific prefix for each form). Feel free to upvote/mark accepted if the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

After some tweaking, I managed to solve the localstorage issue, not a very smart way but it works... I have yet to solve the cookie issue

the id of my boxes works by page no. followed by question no. followed by option

hence 31a is page 3 question 1 option A so I managed to strip the last letter and delete everything within '31'

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    // a key must is used for the cookie/storage
    var prefix = 'com_hop_boxes_';
    var storedData = getStorage(prefix);

    $('div.check_box input:checkbox').bind('change', function() {
        $('#' + this.id + 'box').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
        // save the data on change
        storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'not');
    }).each(function() {
        // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
        var val = storedData.get(this.id);
        if (val == 'checked')
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        if (val == 'not')
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        if (val)
            $(this).trigger('change');
    });
    $('div.radio_button input:radio').bind('change', function() {
        $('#' + this.id + 'box').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));

        var sch = prefix + this.id;
        sch = sch.slice(0, -1);
        var sch = new RegExp(sch);

        Object.keys(localStorage)
                .forEach(function(key) {
            if (sch.test(key) && !(/box$/.test(key))) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        });

        // save the data on change
        storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'not');
    }).each(function() {
        // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
        var val = storedData.get(this.id);
        if (val == 'checked')
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        if (val)
            $(this).trigger('change');
    });
    $('.addtext').bind('change', function() {
        storedData.set(this.id, $(this).val());
    }).each(function() {
        // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
        var val = storedData.get(this.id);
        $(this).val(val);
    });
```